# Text on end of section

Tags: sectioning, xetex, titlesec

Each section starts in new page. I want draw to the end of section some shape (put text or image). It does not matter. For clarity draw big `\char"2055` if enough of free space to the end of page (more than 80 mm)

Which script running on end of section?

How can I know, what I have enough free space to end?

```
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{
\clearpage\thispagestyle{headings}\vspace*{1pc}
}
```

Put code here not that. This calls before first section start and not call if new part starts

Comment: Use an environment instead of `\section` and do your checks against `\pagegoal` in the end part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use leaders.

The `\sectionbreak` command checks whether the available space is greater than a set minimum (here 2cm). If it is it adds a glob of glue which is actually a box containing the ornament and as high as the available space, so we can center the ornament in it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{adforn} % for ornaments

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newlength{\ornamentheight}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{%
  \par
  \setlength{\ornamentheight}{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax}%
  \ifdim\ornamentheight>2cm
    \cleaders\vbox to \ornamentheight{
      \vfill
      \centering
      \fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
      \adforn{21}\quad\adforn{11}\quad\adforn{49}
      \vfill}%
    \vskip\ornamentheight
  \fi
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\lipsum[1-4]

\sectionbreak
\section{Second}

\lipsum[1-5]

\sectionbreak
\section{Third}

\lipsum[2]

\sectionbreak

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code provides two things: (1) an environment form (`mysection`) for sections and (2) calculating the space left on a page (`\calcspaceleft`) together with an example of their use.

```
 % secprob.tex  SE 524061 Text at end of section
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\makeatletter
% calculate the space left (\spaceleft) on the page
\newlength{\spaceleft}
\newcommand{\calcspaceleft}{\par \penalty-100
  \setlength{\spaceleft}{\pagegoal} 
  \addtolength{\spaceleft}{-\pagetotal}}
\newcommand{\printlogo}{\calcspaceleft\ifdim\spaceleft>1in
                        \center LOGO \par \fi}

% an environmental form for \section
\newenvironment{mysection}[2][]%
  {\@ifmtarg{#1}{\section{#2}}{\section[#1]{#2}}}%
  {\printlogo}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{mysection}{First}
  \lipsum[1]
\calcspaceleft Space left is \the\spaceleft.
\end{mysection}

\begin{mysection}[Short]{Long}
%\begin{mysection}{Long}
  \lipsum[2]
\calcspaceleft Space left is \the\spaceleft.
\end{mysection}

\begin{mysection}{Third}
  \lipsum[3]
\calcspaceleft Space left is \the\spaceleft.
\end{mysection}

\end{document}
```

You can use `\calcspaceleft ... \spaceleft` to decide whether or not to add something at the "end" of your section (even add it to the end of the `mysection` environment definition.

The `\calcspaceleft` macro is based on the `needspace` package code.